# link issue - locating where link points to

Tags: php, hyperlink

I have a script I'm trying to install, in the one file there is a link:

a href='?install=b' class="btn btn-info btn-md"

Where do I find where install=b links to o? In the file itself or is it in an install.php file?

Comment: Your question is little bit confusing. Please explain..

Comment: The file final.php has that code in it, but when clicking the link it just goes to somewhere that loops /install /install /install etc...

Comment: apart that single quotes are not valid html, it should link to `/wherever/you/are/on/the/page/index.php?install=b` - if the server is sanly configured. The install=b is not a file but a parameter (that is, if no routing catches it)

Comment: I need to see where link is supposed to go to and check the file locations on the server are right.  Is it targeting something defined in current file or is it in a different install.php file?

Comment: @MartinEvans from what you have shown - there is no indication of a `install.php` file

Comment: Thanks, so in the file i have it will define what the install b route is?

Answer (score 0):

Link points to current address (*blank href*) and sets GET variable "`instal`" to "`b`" (`?instal=b`)

Answer (score 0):

I am not understand verymush about your question try this

```
href='/?install=b' class="btn btn-info btn-md"
```